# accessing static resource in apex

Tags: apex, static-resources

I know that we can access static resources in visualforce page as follows;

```
  {!URLFOR($Resource.UploadTemplate)}
```

How can we access the static resource in APEX class? And if it is in a zip file, how can I specify the specific file from within the zip as it is allowed in visualforce ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to access zip static resource in VF page ? If it is a zip then use like `{!URLFOR($Resource.StyleZip, 'basic.css')}`  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_stylesheet.htm

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to get some file from zipped static resource, you can use getContent():

```
StaticResource static_resource = [SELECT Id, SystemModStamp
                                  FROM StaticResource 
                                  WHERE Name = 'My Zip Array'
                                  LIMIT 1];
String url_file_ref = '/resource/'
                    + String.valueOf(((DateTime)static_resource.get('SystemModStamp')).getTime())
                    + '/' 
                    + static_resource.get('Name')
                    + '/myfile.json';
PageReference file_ref = new PageReference(url_file_ref);
String res_json_body = file_ref.getContent().toString();
```

Please, remember, you can not always use this due to limitation on getContent() (it can not be used in triggers) and latest salesforce updates.

References:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContent.htm

Comment: I don't know if it is more recent than this comment. But there is an Apex Method to do that instead of building manually the path: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_forResource.htm

    PageReference fileRef = PageReference.forResource(staticResourceName, path);
String srBody = fileRef.getContent().toString();

Comment: Second link in References gives 404. Please update or remove link.

Answer (score 41):

You can simply query them.

```
StaticResource sr = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'MyJsonFile' LIMIT 1];
String body = sr.Body.toString();
```

[Access Static Resource](https://www.xgeek.net/en/salesforce/access-static-resources-from-apex-visualforce-and-custom-button/)

Comment: That gives just the URL for resource, not content.

Comment: @zaitsman if you are viewing in DC then it will display as URL but in actual you will get the blob data in apex.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the `PageReference.forResource()` method, then add the path/filename onto it.

```
String myUrl = PageReference.forResource('MyStaticResource').getUrl();
myUrl = myUrl.subString(0, myUrl.indexOf('?'));
system.debug(myUrl + '/path/myImage.png');
```

`PageReference.forResource('MyStaticResource').getUrl()` return a string with the base URL and a number of parameters you don't need, which is why I've used the subString method.

Comment: Interestingly I have had trouble with PageReference.forResource(name). We are trying to use this like "PageReference.forResource(name).getContent().toString()" to actually resolve the content of a static resource and to get it as a string. This works perfectly in anonymous apex, and worked OK when the code was unpackaged, but fails when we put the code in a managed package and install that on a target org. We get an InvalidParameterValueException with message "Static Resource does not exist". Running the apex in anon apex on that same org works fine too.

I don't know why. Permissions?

Comment: In a managed package you need to prefix everything like so: `PageReference.forResource(prefix + '__' + name).getContent().toString();`

Answer (score 5):

Found out a way to do so recently

`PageReference.forResource(resourceName).getUrl()` or `PageReference.forResource(zipName, path).getUrl()` provides the URL of a static resource from Apex code.

Append that with your orgs base url to form a fully usable URL

Example:

```
URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+''+PageReference.forResource(<Static Resource Name>).getUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following (omit the `zip` file extension in the `resourceName`):

`PageReference.forResource('ZipFile', 'Resource.txt').getContent();`

Note that this doesn't work in unit tests as this requires a callout.