# How to get URL for SLDS standard asset in Apex Code?

Tags: slds, urlfor, asset

[In Summer 17 Release (v.40) Salesforce provided a way to retrieve URL for item inside Static Resource within Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_forResource.htm) which was very required feature and which was asked many times (like in this [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107584/accessing-static-resource-in-apex)).

I have a question, is there any viable way to get URL in Apex for standard salesforce SLDS asset?

In Visualforce it is possible to use something like 
`{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/images/profile_avatar_96.png')}`
but I haven't found any way to do this in Apex.

It is not possible to query that object since this is not `Asset` or `ContentAsset` object instance.

If only I knew the URL I could use it to fetch the content like new `PageReference(url_file_ref).getContent().toString();`

I could achieve this if I download SLDS as resource and upload it as static resource but since it is provided like some kind of assets I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Have you tried /sfsites/c/file-asset/{name}? In Communities I used {communityName}/s/sfsites/c/file-asset/{name}

Comment: @ytiq I am using PageReference sprite = new PageReference('/_slds/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg'); - however, this might be fragile if Salesforce moves those files

Comment: then try uploading it asset and then using PageReference sprite = new PageReference('/sfsites/c/file-asset/symbols');

Comment: I don't want to upload anything since it is already available in Visualforce

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following way to achieve this. I have created a Visualforce page `Urlfor`

```
<apex:page controller="UrlforController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!c}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and a class `UrlforController`

```
public inherited sharing class UrlforController {
    private static final String START = 'UrlforStart(';
    private static final String FINISH = ')UrlforFinish';

    public UrlforController() {
        text = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('text');
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'text   ' + text);
    }

    public String text { get; set; }

    public Component.Apex.OutputText getC() {
        Component.Apex.OutputText outputText = new Component.Apex.OutputText();
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'text   ' + text);
        outputText.expressions.value = START + text + FINISH;
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'outputText.value   ' + outputText.value);

        return outputText;
    }

    public static String get(String expression) {
        PageReference r = Page.Urlfor;
        r.getParameters().put('text', expression);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'r.getContent().toString()   ' + r.getContent().toString().substringBetween(START, FINISH));
    }

}
```

Then I use `UrlforController.get('{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS,\'/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#announcement\')}')` to get the actual URL `/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#announcement`

Comment: An interesting "hack" :)

Comment: @PhilW this is reuse of old hack used to get translated text of label in Apex code